# Some Changes To Make Here In This Tlc Script

Tags: scripting, tcl, eggdrop

Now the script is work great, but need to change the commands and remove channel name, when i add IP in exemp.txt file list,
someone can help here, how to change this public comand , thx in advance

```
!exemp help change in !help
!exemp list change in !list
!exemp del 1 change in !del 75.34.37.12  75.34.37.* 75.34.*
!exemp add change in !add 75.34.37.12 75.34.37.*  75.34.*
```

and to remove the name channel when i add Ip on exemp.txt list
to add only the IP cozz is added and channel name with Ip on file exemp.txt

```
#Test 75.34.37.12
```

thank you in advance

```
proc check_ip {ip} {
   set file [open "exemp.txt" r]
   set fdata [split [read $file] \n]
   close $file
   foreach entry $fdata {
      if {[string match $entry $ip]} {
         return 1
      }
   }
   return 0
}

bind pub n|n !exemp  exemp:cmd

set exemp(file) "exemp.txt"

if {![file exists $exemp(file)]} {
   set file [open $exemp(file) w]
   close $file
}

proc exemp:cmd {nick host hand chan arg} {
   global exemp

   set arg0 [lindex [split $arg] 0]
   set arg1 [lindex [split $arg] 1]
if {$arg0 == ""} {
   putserv "NOTICE $nick :EXEMP Use: \002!exemp help\002 for more informations."
   return
}
switch $arg0 {
   add {
if {$arg1 == ""} {
   putserv "NOTICE $nick :EXEMP Use: \002!exemp help\002 for more informations."
   return
}
   set file [open $exemp(file) a]
   puts $file "$chan $arg1"
   close $file
   putserv "NOTICE $nick :EXEMP I added\002 $arg1 \002in my ExempList."
   }

   list {
   set file [open $exemp(file) "r"]
   set read [read -nonewline $file]
   close $file
   set data [split $read "\n"]
   set i 0
if {$data == ""} {
   putserv "NOTICE $nick :EXEMP There are\002 no IP \002added to ExempList."
   return
}
   putserv "NOTICE $nick :EXEMP The list of IP added in my ExempList."
foreach line $data {
   set read_chan [lindex [split $line] 0]
if {[string match -nocase $read_chan $chan]} {
   set i [expr $i +1]
   set read_blackchan [lindex [split $line] 1]
   putserv "NOTICE $nick :$i.) $read_blackchan"
         }
      }
   }


   del {
   array set exempdel [list]
if {![regexp {.*?(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).*?\((.*?)\)} $arg1]} {
   putserv "NOTICE $nick :EXEMP Use: \002!exemp help\002 for more informations."
   return
}


set file [open $exemp(file) "r"]
   set data [read -nonewline $file]
   close $file
   set lines [split $data "\n"]
   set counter -1
   set line_counter -1
   set current_place -1
foreach line $lines {
   set line_counter [expr $line_counter + 1]
   set read_chan [lindex [split $line] 0]
if {[string match -nocase $read_chan $chan]} {
   set counter [expr $counter + 1]
   set exempdel($counter) $line_counter
   }
}

foreach place [array names exempdel] {
   if {$place == [expr $arg1 - 1]} {
   set current_place $exempdel($place)
   }
}

if {$current_place == "-1"} {
   putserv "NOTICE $nick :EXEMP The entry number\002 $arg1 \002does not exist."   
   return   
}

   set delete [lreplace $lines $current_place $current_place]
   set files [open $exemp(file) "w"]
   puts $files [join $delete "\n"]
   close $files
   set file [open $exemp(file) "r"]
   set data [read -nonewline $file]
   close $file
if {$data == ""} {
   set files [open $exemp(file) "w"]
   close $files
}
   putserv "NOTICE $nick :EXEMP The entry number\002 $arg1 \002was removed from ExempList."

   }

   help {
   putserv "NOTICE $nick :EXEMP You can add IP using: \002!exemp add <IP>\002 "
   putserv "NOTICE $nick :EXEMP To see all the IP in ExempList use:\002 !exemp list\002"
   putserv "NOTICE $nick :EXEMP To delete a IP use:\002 !exemp del <number>\002 (from the ExempList)"
      }
   }
}
```

How is work now

```
<BoB> !exemp add 75.34.37.12
TestBot EXEMP I added 75.34.37.12 in my ExempList.
<BoB> !exemp list
TestBot EXEMP The list of IP added in my ExempList.
TestBot 1.) 75.34.37.12
<BoB> !exemp del 1
TestBot EXEMP The entry number 1 was removed from ExempList.
<BoB> !exemp list
TestBot EXEMP There are no  IP added to ExempList.
<BoB> !exemp del 75.34.37.12
 TestBot EXEMP Use: !exemp help for more informations.
 <BoB> !exemp help
 TestBot EXEMP You can add IP using: !exemp add <IP>
 TestBot EXEMP To see all the IP in ExempList use: !exemp list
 TestBot- EXEMP To delete a IP use: !exemp del <number> (from the ExempList}
```

Comment: Hello Elvis.welcome to Stackoverflow. It is not very clear what your problem is. Can you add more information about what you're trying to do and the problems and what you've tried?

Comment: I make this code now is work but need to remove channel name when i add IP and to del ip same as i add ip not with item number on file, and to change the public comman, thx